Solving ODEs with PETSc4py?
I'm trying to get started with PETSc to solve ODEs in Python. In this code I try to solve a simple y'=-ky however it is outputting just 0s as solution. I canont see where the mistake is and neither can ChatGPT4 , any help is largely appreciated.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import petsc4py
from petsc4py import PETSc
import sys
from petsc4py.PETSc import TS
petsc4py.init()

# ODE to be solved
def f(t, y,ydot,k):
    ydot = -k * y
    
k = 0.5

# Set up Petsc environment
PETSc.Sys.popErrorHandler()

# Create the time stepper
ts = TS().create()
ts.setType('bdf')  # backward differentiation formula

# time t and nr of steps ns
t = 100
ns = 30

ts.setProblemType(TS.ProblemType.NONLINEAR)
ts.setRHSFunction(f)
ts.setFromOptions()
ts.setMaxTime(t)  # set the time 
ts.setTimeStep(t/ns)

# Set up the initial condition
y0_0 = np.array([1.0]) 

# Set up the Petsc vector for the initial condition
y = PETSc.Vec().createWithArray(y0_0)

# Set up the Petsc vector for the solution
y_solution = PETSc.Vec().create()

# Set initial condition
ts.setTime(0.0)
ts.setSolution(y)

# Solve
# ts.solve(y)
solution_times = []
solution_values = []

while not ts.getTime() >= ts.getMaxTime():
    ts.step()
    # ts.getSolution(y)
    solution_times.append(ts.getTime())
    solution_values.append(y[0])

# Plot the solution
plt.plot(solution_times, solution_values)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()


I've tried many options (e.g. using ts.solve(y) instead of ts.step()) but I always get errors like returned null without setting an exception.
I expect it to output the exponential function that solves the ODE in def f.

did you try the docs, here:  https://pypi.org/project/petsc4py

and also here: https://petsc.org/release/

Thank you, still doesn't solve my problem. My goal is to get a solution array that contains the solution at each time step so that it can be plotted right away. In those examples it seems like the code only returns initial and final state
